# Poisson random variable power series

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Suppose X is a Poisson λ random variable. 
(1) What is P(X is even)? 
(2) By manipulating power series, compute
$$
E [X(X − 1)(X − 2)· · ·(X + 1 − l)]
$$
for each $l$ = 1, 2, 3,....

For (1), using taylor series expansion of $e^λ$.I got

$$
P(x=even) = (1/2)(1+e^{-2λ}) 
$$

I think the power series I need to use is the expansion of $e^λ$, which is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{λ}/k!
$$

but I don't know how to use this to calculate (2)

Comment: Part (2) is unrelated to (1). Write out $E[X(X-1)\dots(X-l+1)]$ using $E[f(X)]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k)P(X=k)$, then simplify.

Comment: The power series expansion of $e^\lambda$ is not correct. It should be $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
E[X(X-1)...(X-(l-1))] &= \sum_{k=l}^{\infty} k(k-1)...(k-(l-1))\ P(X=k) \\
&= \sum_{k=l}^{\infty} \frac{k!}{(k-l)!} \frac{\lambda^k.e^{-\lambda}}{k!} \\
&= e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=l}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^k}{(k-l)!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda}.\lambda^l.\sum_{k'=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{k'}}{k'!} \\
&= \lambda^l
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

1 seems to be correct.

For the second i would use the probability generating function and use the property that its lth derivarive evaluated at 1 is $E[X(X-1)...(X+1-l)]$.